# Django 1.5 : OperationalError in windows when running "python manage.py syncdb" using postgresql-psycopg2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.2

This is my settings.py file in my Django project. OS : Windows, hosting : localhost

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',                     
        'USER': 'JESS',
        'PASSWORD': 'dreamhost',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                     
        'PORT': '5432',                     
    }
}
```

I followed instructions from this blog in installing PostgreSQL and psycopg2

http://shivul.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/installing-django-with-postgresql-on-windows-and-ubuntu/

and when running `python manage.py syncdb` I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)  and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432
```

I even tried to edit settings through pgadmin3 application in PostgreSQL installation files, it even throws the same error

```
Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)  and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432
```

I looked through similar questions in stackoverflow and internet, everything is outdated or not working.

Comment: In database settings, why is your port set to `8000` ? Change it to `5432`

Comment: @karthik : Thankyou..I still face another issue OperationalError : FATAL : password authetication failed for user "JESS"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server is listening only on IPv4, but `localhost` is resolving to both an IPv4 and IPv6 address on your host.

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to force an IPv4 connection, or edit `postgresql.conf` to tell your PostgreSQL to listen on IPv6 too. Show the `listen_addresses` line of `postgresql.conf` for advice on that, along with the output of `select version()`.

Comment: Thank you Craig, I have changed localhost value and my listen_address has '*' #for all ,but I face a new error now:(OperationalError) FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user “username”

Comment: I have looked through your other answers on similar problem "to edit pg_hba.conf to md5.." I tried it..and it's still throwing the same error

Comment: @jess.intutive then you edited the wrong `pg_hba.conf` line or you forgot to restart PostgreSQL after the edit.

Comment: Thanks Craig: I have edited the pg_hba.conf file and it's working but I have changed the access from "md5" to "trust" for all settings, would it be a problem after I launch my web app?

Comment: @jess.intutive Well, it's a *terrible* idea unless you've restricted it to connections from localhost and you *absolutely* trust everything on the local machine, including all other scripts and code you will ever run as any user. I strongly recommend using `md5` and setting a suitable password. Please read the client authentication chapter of the PostgreSQL documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the exact same message recently but the cause/solution for my problem was different.  I am not exactly sure what screwed me up but I think it was when I was seeing what happens when you run the clearsessions function in manage.py.

In the end I needed to restart the postgresql service.

To do this (Windows 7),

1. launch your task manager (CTRL+ALT+DEL)
2. go to the services tab
3. click the services button in the bottom right.

(you can also search for 'View local services' in the start menu)

In the services window:
 4. find postgresql-XXXX. 
 5. Click on it and start it if it is stopped.

If it is already running you might as well restart it since your there and see if it helps.  My issue was specifically that the service was not restarting on boot.